# Websocket with Play! Framework is failing with vhosts

Tags: playframework, websocket, vhosts

I am unable to create a websocket with vhots enabled through apache2 on my local machine. In FF:

```
WebSocket is not defined
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://test.localhost.in/soc')
```

Chrome gives a 404 Error.

Routes file has been defined properly.

```
WS      /soc                                    Home.HomeWebSocket.listen
```

VHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ServerName localhost.in
    ServerAlias *.localhost.in
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
    SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</VirtualHost>
```

I can confirm it is due to VHosts because I can successfully run the chat example through localhost:9000/ but not test.localhost.in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache's proxy module apparently does not know about WebSockets.
You could try to use [mod_pywebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/).

Also have a look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/290121/configuring-apache2-to-proxy-websocket).

Comment: With Play! which is better: running apache or Nginx?

Comment: That question is too general to answer it simply. I personally am running Play behind nginx, but that's just a matter of taste -- I don't really have any high performance requirements. I suggest that you write down what you need from your front-end HTTP server (e.g. load balancing, virtual hosts, WebSocket support) and check which webserver supports it. Then test/benchmark the ones you like. The manual has a section on [webserver configuration](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/production) and [deployment options](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/deployment).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking through the docs and read that nearly 9.7% of the net was served from nginx servers in Feb 2012. Many large russian websites like Yandex etc use it

Comment: for a 'static' usage as a frontend nginx is definitely a better option that apache2 - really suited the task, lighter and faster, great caching system, etc. Alternatives exist, such as [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/). For hosting a dynamic website (wsgi, php, etc.) the answer is of course more complex... Beware that nginx conf can be a hell for newbies! my 2 cents

Comment: @Carsten could you please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372722/vhots-nginx-config-for-playframework-websockets