# VHosts Nginx Config for Playframework Websockets

Tags: nginx, playframework, websocket

The config below seemed to have worked but now its failing. I followed this [article](http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets) to download and install the tcp_proxy_module.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #server {

    #}


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration

    server {
        listen       80;
       #listen       locahost:8080;
        server_name  localhost.in;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
         }
    }

}
```

**Update:**

Nginx Error Log:

```
2012/02/21 10:56:59 [error] 14745#0: *278 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost.in, request: "GET /websocket/room/socket?roomNo=1&user=sameerFF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/websocket/room/socket?roomNo=1&user=sameerFF", host: "test.localhost.in"
2012/02/21 10:56:59 [error] 14745#0: *257 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost.in, request: "GET /websocket/room/socket?roomNo=1&user=sameerChrome HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/websocket/room/socket?roomNo=1&user=sameerChrome", host: "test.localhost.in"
2012/02/21 10:59:40 [error] 15366#0: *10 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost.in, request: "GET /websocket/room/socket?roomNo=1&user=sameerFF HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/websocket/room/socket?roomNo=1&user=sameerFF", host: "test.localhost.in"
```

**Updated 2:**

With this config I get a bind exception when I start nginx. If I remove the tcp settings, nginx comes up alright. I need port 80 to redirect to 9000 for both regular http requests as well as WebSocket requests

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

tcp {
     upstream websockets {
      ## Play! location
       server 127.0.0.1:9000;
     }   

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost.in;

        tcp_nodelay on;
        proxy_pass websockets;
   }
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration

    server {
        listen       80;
#listen       locahost:8080;
        server_name  localhost.in;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: How is it failing? Is there an error message from nginx or in the log files (after you re-enable the error log, of course :) )? Is it just the Websockets part that's not working?

Comment: I have added the error log entries for the chat example and they look like TimeOutExceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's just the websockets that are not working. Please read the [article you linked](http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets) again. You did not modify your nginx configuration.

According to that article, a sample configuration for you might look like this (I have not tested it yet, though):

```
tcp {
    upstream websockets {
        ## Play! location
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }   

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost.in;

        tcp_nodelay on;
        proxy_pass websockets;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried your solution but got a bind exception on start (please see my edits to the question). Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well of course you get a bind exception, you're trying to bind to port 80 twice. Try it without the whole `http{...}` section. The `tcp{...}` section should automatically route everything (both traditional HTTP requests as well as Websocket stuff) to the play server.